# What is the best way to establish a local connection between a native client application and a webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

I have a USB device with some buttons on it communicating with the host (Windows and Mac) over a proprietary HID control interface. On the host, I have a native application communicating to the device (e.g. receiving button press events, or configuring the device).

Now I´m looking for a proper way to handle button events or device configuration in Javascript on a website running in Chrome and ideally also in Firefox (and nice-to-have in other browsers as well).
So, I need a connection between Javascript running in the browser, and my native application running on the client machine.

My first approach would be to use Chrome extensions via native messaging. I guess that´d do the job, however there might be some drawbacks. Two components would need to be installed and maintained (the extension and the native messaging host), and it would be limited to Chrome and maybe Firefox (slightly modified) and future Edge based on Chromium. 
Furthermore, while I´m sure the Chrome extension is able to talk to my native application, I´m not so sure how any webpage can communicate with the extension without raising some security issues which need to be taken care of.

So I was thinking about a connection via WebSockets. The native client application could run a WebSocket server and the webpage could connect to localhost. For instance, I have seen [Enpass](https://www.enpass.io/) doing something similar. But what if the webpage is https? Wouldn´t that require the installation of a certificate on localhost? Is that even possible? What about the [concerns](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) from LetsEncrypt?

I know there are several stackoverflow questions targeted at these issues, but I have not found satisfying answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have used websocket approach in the past. What you can do is have a single Websocket connection in the background script and use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from content script to background script to send messages to websockets. This way https won't be an issue (not sure if it's an issue otherwise either).

> I´m not so sure how any webpage can communicate with the extension
>   without raising some security issues which need to be taken care of.

I've never used native messaging personally but I'm sure all issues can be solved if you start working on it and ask specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! The idea with the background script requires an extension again, which I wanted to get rid of by using WebSockets in the first place.
Don´t get me wrong, I believe a solution as suggested by you would work fine, but what advantage would it bring compared to using a chrome extension communicating to the native app via native messaging? Only the native messaging connection would be replaced by a WebSocket connection.

Comment: @pbert you tagged the question with chrome extension that's why i assumed you want an extension. Advantage of websocket is it is simpler to setup than native messaging imo.